# infimum of function of two distincts variables

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am a little bit confused about the definition of infmum of a function of two variables. Let $\lambda_n = 1 - e^{-n}$ and $\beta = {\{\lambda_n}\}_{n >0}$. . I would like to compute $$ \inf_{\alpha \neq \mu \in \beta}\frac{\alpha - \mu}{1 - \alpha \cdot \mu}$$ I don't see what this infimum means exactly. Is it applied to $\alpha$ or $\mu$. 
I really need you help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the notation $\alpha \times \mu$ and not $\alpha \cdot \mu$ ?

Comment: No, I am just not used to tex. @Rebellos

Comment: Where do $\alpha$ and $\mu$ belong to ?

Comment: They belong to $\beta$

Answer (score 0):

The infimum is over the set of $\alpha$ and $\mu$ in $\beta$ such that $\alpha \neq \mu$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f : \beta \to \mathbb R$ such that :

$$f(a) = \frac{\alpha - \mu}{1 - \alpha \cdot \mu}$$

The expression

$$\inf_{\alpha \neq \mu \in \beta}\frac{\alpha - \mu}{1 - \alpha \cdot \mu}$$

means that you want to find the infimum of the function $f(a)$ with respect to $a$ when it's not equal to $\mu$ and they both belong to $\beta$.

The infimum of $f(a)$ is the greatest element in $\mathbb R$ such that is less than or equal to all elements of $f^{-1}(\mathbb R)$, meaning the image of $f$.

Now, in order to find it, let $\alpha, \mu \in \beta$ with $\alpha \neq \mu$ and :

$$\alpha = 1 - e^{-\ell}, \mu = 1-e^{-m}$$

Then :

$$\inf_{a\neq \mu \in \beta} \frac{\alpha - \mu}{1-\alpha\cdot \mu} = \inf_{\ell \in \mathbb N \neq m \in \mathbb N} \frac{e^{-\ell} - e^{-m}}{1-(1-e^{-\ell})(1-e^{-m})}$$

Comment: Ok, and then I think this will give us that the infimum is equal to zero? @Rebellos

Comment: @user12313 It would be, if it could be $\ell  = \mu$. But it's not, since we want $\ell \neq \mu$.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't know how to compute this infimum then? @Rebellos

Comment: @user12313 The question was about what infimum means that over what variable is defined or how to find it ?

Comment: I could say the two, I would like to understand it and compute it. Thanks for your explanations @Rebellos

Comment: @user12313 Hmm, an attempt would behandling it like an ordinary function by differentiating and finding a minimum.

Comment: I don't see how to do that over two variables, could you give me more explications please @Rebellos

Comment: You are not doing it over two variables.  As it is mentioned many times, you are finding the infimum with respect to $\alpha$ which means that you should differentiate with respect to $\ell$. But I really think you should work by yourself now since you have all these explained. You shouldn't be expecting a thorough solution to your probable homework.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, no it's not a homework @Rebellos